Celery doesn't process my tasks but it doesn't throw any errors either
I am trying to create a queue system for an llm helper I am developing for a job. I settled for redis and celery since I have no prior experience with any queue system and it seemed simple enough.
I tried implementing it into my app directly but while everything seemed to be working, I could never get results back with the task ids. So i made a simple app with just one function to understand what is happening and it still doesn't work.
Here is my code:
app.py
import time

from flask import Flask, request
from celery import Celery, Task

from logging import Logger
logger = Logger("testcelery", level="INFO")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    CELERY=dict(
        broker_url="redis://localhost:6379/0",
        result_backend="redis://localhost:6379/0"
    ),
)

celery = Celery(app.name)
celery.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
celery.set_default()
app.extensions["celery"] = celery


@celery.task
def useless_trash(name: str) -> str:
    time.sleep(10)
    return f"Hello {name}"


@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def post_task() -> tuple:
    task = useless_trash.delay(request.args.get("name"))
    logger.info(task)
    return {"task_id": task.id}, 200


@app.route('/<task_id>', methods=["GET"])
def get_task(task_id: str) -> tuple:
    task = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)
    logger.info(task)
    if not task.ready():
        return {"status": "Task not found"}, 404
    if task.state == "PENDING":
        return {"status": "Processing"}, 200
    elif task.state == "SUCCESS":
        return {"status": "Complete", "result": task.get()}, 200
    else:
        return {"status": "Error", "message": str(task.info)}, 500


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return "Hello, I am working."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


I have redis running in a docker container.
I have celery in a cmd prompt running from: celery -A app.celery worker -c 5 -l DEBUG
I have celery beat running in a cmd prompt from: celery -A app.celery beat -l DEBUG
I have flask running in a cmd prompt from: flask run
None of the cmd prompt show any error messages. When I send a task through it shows up in the celery worker cmd prompt:
[2024-05-07 11:57:05,370: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.useless_trash[390da1bb-edda-48c2-a5ed-958aff37e710] received
[2024-05-07 11:57:05,370: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function fast_trace_task at 0x000001E685F4D8A0> (args:('app.useless_trash', '390da1bb-edda-48c2-a5ed-958aff37e710', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'app.useless_trash', 'id': '390da1bb-edda-48c2-a5ed-958aff37e710', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': '390da1bb-edda-48c2-a5ed-958aff37e710', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': "('Maxime',)", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen47124@DESKTOP-SFVC8EF', 'ignore_result': False, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}, 'properties': {'correlation_id': '390da1bb-edda-48c2-a5ed-958aff37e710', 'reply_to': '3ef32eb9-c48a-3414-a9f6-aaee43732d55', 'delivery_mode': 2, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}, 'priority': 0, 'body_encoding': 'base64', 'delivery_tag': '73d6523b-d7b6-49dd-9288-ae43f183b388'}, 'reply_to': '3ef32eb9-c48a-3414-a9f6-aaee43732d55', 'correlation_id': '390da1bb-edda-48c2-a5ed-958aff37e710', 'hostname': 'celery@DESKTOP-SFVC8EF', 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key':... kwargs:{})

If I submit multiple requests they show up in redis under the celery key as (not the same task_id as the previous one, that's normal):
1) "{\"body\": \"W1siTWF4aW1lIl0sIHt9LCB7ImNhbGxiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJlcnJiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJjaGFpbiI6IG51bGwsICJjaG9yZCI6IG51bGx9XQ==\", \"content-encoding\": \"utf-8\", \"content-type\": \"application/json\", \"headers\": {\"lang\": \"py\", \"task\": \"app.useless_trash\", \"id\": \"d629054f-7958-45d1-9778-9fd9425bb477\", \"shadow\": null, \"eta\": null, \"expires\": null, \"group\": null, \"group_index\": null, \"retries\": 0, \"timelimit\": [null, null], \"root_id\": \"d629054f-7958-45d1-9778-9fd9425bb477\", \"parent_id\": null, \"argsrepr\": \"('Maxime',)\", \"kwargsrepr\": \"{}\", \"origin\": \"gen84044@DESKTOP-SFVC8EF\", \"ignore_result\": false, \"replaced_task_nesting\": 0, \"stamped_headers\": null, \"stamps\": {}}, \"properties\": {\"correlation_id\": \"d629054f-7958-45d1-9778-9fd9425bb477\", \"reply_to\": \"f523c065-e666-35dd-9bb2-85d2f17ba84e\", \"delivery_mode\": 2, \"delivery_info\": {\"exchange\": \"\", \"routing_key\": \"celery\"}, \"priority\": 0, \"body_encoding\": \"base64\", \"delivery_tag\": \"763b8805-7149-4018-8e26-89b8399750e7\"}}"

Nothing appears in the celery beat cmd prompt.
When I try to get info on a task with it's task id, it always gives me a task not found message and nothing ever seems to be processed and stays exactly the same in redis.
I am unsure what steps I need to take to correct the problem, but reading the documentation and trying to get an llm to help me has led me in circles and I need some pointers to lead me out of it.
Thank you very much.

Can you confirm that the app name that you're starting the worker with matches the name of the Celery app that you're initializing? From what you've shared, it looks like the Celery app is being named "app" but the worker is being started with -A app.celery. These values should match.

@schwartz721 I use app.celery to target the celery object directly because only using app gives me the error message
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'
It was suggested in another SO thread that to fix it I needed to do app.celery.
